# Does Stack Overflow not do community ads?

Tags: support, advertising

I'm curious to see why Stack Overflow doesn't provide an options for the community to place community ads: there are open source ads, but they don't have the option of having community ads, like all other graduated sites.

While I can understand that Stack Overflow might not allow community-based ads for a few reasons, I'm curious as to what those reasons are. The option to advertise Open Source projects is great, but it's *just* open source. What about other sites? It seems contrary to the tag wiki:

> Community Promotion Ads started as free advertising on Stack Overflow for open source projects in 2009. In 2011, the project was expanded to include free vote-based advertising for all Stack Exchange communities. Ads should be for projects, tools, conferences, etc. relevant to the site, such as:
>
> - Highlighting and promoting activities in the per-site community blogs
> - Cool applications or open-source projects related to the site
> - The site’s Twitter feed
> - Promoting relevant events or conferences the community should know about
> - Anything else the community would genuinely be interested in

Also, aren't we due to refresh the ads?